# How can I remove the format part of the string?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have this table:

```
// image_path
+----+-----------------------------+
| id |           path              |
+----+-----------------------------+
| 1  | 3498uhrf34i098jf349jf43.png |
| 2  | mfij948t5498hj43h9f34p0.jpg |
| 3  | fcnh9348jmof9348i34f435.png |
| 4  | 3049jr430okf43p0ijfr43f.gif |
| 5  | oi3094jfo439ijf430f443r.jpg |
| 6  | 3f0irj03409iko4p3rfo04f.png |
+----+-----------------------------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM image_path WHERE path = :token;
//                             ^^^^ removing everything from the right side until dot
```

So here is an example:

```
SELECT * FROM image_path WHERE path = 'fcnh9348jmof9348i34f435';
/* output:
+----+-----------------------------+
| 3  | fcnh9348jmof9348i34f435.png |
+----+-----------------------------+
*/
```

How can I do that?

Comment: An alternative is to modify the database schema, split into two columns; `path` and `extension`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `like`:

```
where path like concat('fcnh9348jmof9348i34f435', '.%')
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad05c9/20) is a SQL Fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want to get the part before the first period, then use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(path, '.', 1)
```

Comment: @Shafizadeh . . . In your SQL Fiddle, you have a typo -- two `where`s in the query.

Comment: Oh .. you are right, thx .. +1. Noted that the fiddle in your question is also wrong `:-)` *(two `where` clause)*

Comment: @Shafizadeh . . . I fixed the link ;)

Comment: Good :) ..! Also as a consult, do you think which answer is more efficient? I mean which one has a better performance for index? *(because `path` column is unique)*

Comment: They are probably all pretty equivalent with respect to performance.

Comment: Look, I'm worried about this rule: *"You're not using the raw column value, so you couldn't use an index on the `path` column"*. So should I use either `like` or `substring_index` to keep safe against that rule?

Comment: I'm not familiar with such a rule.  I would use `like` because there is the hope that MySQL would use an index when the wildcard is at the end (although this is only true when the pattern is constant).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ([`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)):

```
SELECT * FROM image_path WHERE substring_index(path, '.', '1') = 'fcnh9348jmof9348i34f435';
```

## Demo Here

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**LEFT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [**LOCATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) functions:

```
SELECT LEFT(path, LOCATE('.', path) - 1) FROM image_path;
```